# Jquery blockUI - Centering an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to show a picture with some text in the center of the blockUI.

So far I have managed to do so with absolute positioning but I need it to fit to any res.

This is what I have so far.

```
$('#MainDiv').block({
message: 
    '<div style="position: relative; width: 200px;">' +
        '<img src="pic.png" style="z-index: -1; width:200px" />' +
        '<p style="position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 60px;">wait</p>' +
   '</div>',
css: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    border: 'none'
}
```

});

The problem is that 'MainDiv' can be in different sizes and than for some sizes the my div is not well centered.

Comment: Is this the jQuery plugin in question? [http://malsup.com/jquery/block/](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/)

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle?